# Statistical faults of the article relating GDP growth with certain non-sensical variable

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, methodology

Colleague draw my attention to the following [discussion paper](http://mpra.ub.uni-muenchen.de/32706/). In my opinion this discussion paper is clearly intended as a critique of the routinely published articles in the field. The discussion paper relates the growth of gross domestic product with the length of certain male body part. The relationship is clearly non-sensical, but the author lays out quite convincing argument backed by data and reasonable (at first glance) statistical analysis. My question is are there any statistical faults in author's arguments?

This paper was mentioned in [Freakonomics blog](http://www.freakonomics.com/2011/07/15/for-economic-growth-does-penis-size-matter-more-than-political-system/).

Comment: I intentionally did not mention the article exact name and which non-sensical variable is used. If someone feels otherwise, feel free to change.

Comment: That's why the economy flopped!